# Xamarin Android - Opening WebView after Google-Maps: application is getting crashed in emulator

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.maps

I am using WebView after rendering Xamarin.Forms.Maps (Same Page In App), on first time rendering both everything works as expected, but on the second time rendering (existing the page and reopening) I'm getting a crash only in my android emulator,

My error:

[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 24507 (RenderThread), pid 24445

The crash happens only in android emulator, android device - all good, iOS emulator - all good (no crashes at all).

When setting android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android emulator works good with no crashes and errors, but I want to keep android:hardwareAccelerated="true".

Video with the issue: https://streamable.com/16x209

Xamarin Forms version: same as your sample

SfRichTextEditor: same as your sample

Deployment device specification: https://pasteboard.co/KihBHEF.png

Thank you.

Comment: Does the android device with the android:hardwareAccelerated to false?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT no the physical device android:hardwareAccelerated set to 'true' and working but the emulator is'nt

Comment: I am not sure whether your application does not behave properly with hardware acceleration turned on globally. You could control it for individual activities as well. For more details, please check the link below. https://developer.android.google.cn/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel